# System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid value for key 'authentication'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I have a web app (running on .NET 4.6.1) hosted in an Azure App Service which connects to an Azure SQL Server via SQL Server authentication (username/password) using Entity Framework, inheriting from `DbContext` class from `System.Data.Entity` namespace.

I'm planning to use Active Directory Service Principal authentication mode. Due to this I modified my connection string to

```
Data Source= servername.database.windows.net; Encrypt=True; 
Initial Catalog= dbname; Authentication=Active Directory Service Principal; 
User Id=servicePrincipalID; Password=servicePrincipalPassword;
```

This modified string throws an error

> System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid value for key 'authentication'.'

when trying to open the connection. Many online articles/resources have clear integration for .NET core apps using the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` assembly, however nothing much for apps running on the .NET Framework.

Please let us know if you can guide us.

Answer (score 1):

On [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-service-principal-authentication) states the connection string should be build as shown below:

```
string ConnectionString = @"Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Service Principal; Encrypt=True; Database=testdb; User Id=AppId; Password=secret";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    conn.Open();
}
```

Please note that this type of authentication requires Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version 2.0.0+ on Entity Framework 4.6+.

In addition, you need to create a user in your Azure SQL Database that corresponds to the service principal identity. For example:

```
create user [servicePrincipalID] from external provider;
```

Finally, make sure you setup the required [app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals?tabs=browser).